# How to solve DE where the derivative is in the denominator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following DE of first order.

$\frac{u}{\sqrt{( u')^2+1}}=c$ where c is constant.
The problem that i have is that i don't know how to handle the DE if the derivative is in the denominator.

my attempt was to rewrite the equation to 
$u' = \sqrt{u^2c-1}$ and solve this by separation of variables but this seems not to be right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us what you did and why "this seems not to be right" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct. You may consider  $$u\prime =\pm  \sqrt{(u/c)^2-1}$$ instead of just the positive sign.

To make sure that you have the correct solution, all you have to do is to verify that your solution satisfies the differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

The equation
$$
\frac{u^2}{c^2}-u'^2=1
$$
can be parametrized by hyperbolic functions,
$$
u=c\cosh(v),~~ u'=\sinh(v).
$$
Comparing the derivative of the first expression with the second gives
$$
c\sinh(v)v'=\sinh(v)\implies v'=\frac1c
$$
so that in total $$u(t)=c\cosh(\frac tc).$$

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is a little off, we can rearrange the ODE as follows:

$$
\begin{align}u &= c\sqrt{(u')^2 + 1}
\\
\Big(\dfrac{u}{c}\Big)^2 &= (u')^2 + 1
\\
u' &= \sqrt{\Big(\dfrac{u}{c}\Big)^2 - 1}
\\
\dfrac{u'}{\sqrt{\Big(\dfrac{u}{c}\Big)^2-1}} &= 1
\\
\dfrac{\dfrac{du}{dt}}{\sqrt{\Big(\dfrac{u}{c}\Big)^2-1}} &= 1
\\
\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{\Big(\dfrac{u}{c}\Big)^2-1}} &= dt
\end{align}
$$
I think a trigonometric substitution and integration should help you continue.